# Enable/Disable background music

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

To enable background music from app Spotify or Music app, I use this code:

```
do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }
```

But how can i reverse that, to stop allow background music playing?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories), the chief playback audio session categories are:

> **AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient**
>
> When
> you use this category, audio from other apps mixes with your audio.
>
> **AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient**
>
> By default, using this category implies that your app’s audio is
> nonmixable—activating your session will interrupt any other audio
> sessions which are also nonmixable.
>
> **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback**
>
> By default, using this category implies that your app’s audio is
> nonmixable—activating your session will interrupt any other audio
> sessions which are also nonmixable.

So, you've deliberately picked the *only* playback category which *doesn't* silence nonmixable background audio. If you *do* want to silence nonmixable background audio, pick one of the *other* categories. There's nothing wrong with changing categories at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
private func setIsAudioPlaysInBackground(isPlay: Bool) {
    if isPlay {
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
    } else {
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
    }
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this code?

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
```

I haven't tested it but from what I assume it would stop the music.